# Mostrar a lista de documentos no Firebase Firestore v9.4 via onSnapshot com Reactjs

Tags: firebase, firestore

Alguém sabe como eu consigo mostrar via onSnapshot (renderizando os resultados) com o Firebase Firestore v9.4 com Reactjs, alguns documentos vindos de uma coleção?

Para criar a coleção eu utilizei o seguinte código:

```
let arr = {}; // aqui vem as informações
const  ref = collection(db, userId, "patrimonio", "transacoes"); // userId é o ID do usuário gerado pelo firebase
await setDoc(doc(ref), arr);
```

Nisso o caminho fica dessa forma no firebase

```
/userId/patrimonio/transacoes
```

Nessa coleção "transacoes" estão sendo gravados os dados. Estou tentando renderizar esses dados (ao todo já são 7 registros) mas não estou conseguindo. Estou utilizando o seguinte código

```
const unsub = onSnapshot(doc(db, userId, "patrimonio"), (doc) => {
  console.log("Current data: ", doc.data());
});
```

Não sei como puxar as transações e mesmo pegando o documento "patrimonio" ele não puxa nada, não aparece o nome "transacoes".

Eu consigo fazer esse tipo de consulta e mostrar isso?

Answer (score -1):

Voce precisa consultar a coleção primeiro, e depois o documento.

```
collection(db, "COLEÇAO", "DOCUMENTO")
```

Se nao consegur manda print do firebase, e do erro.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).